# Errors in trying to compile a TikZ diagram with `shorten>=7.5pt, shorten<=7.5pt` key

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am getting errors compiling the following code because I have the optional key `shorten>=7.5pt, shorten<=7.5pt` in one arrow command and the optional key `shorten=7.5pt` in another arrow command. The error message I get is "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/shorten' to which you passed '7.5pt'." I have used these keys in other files and they both compile.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}



\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}



\makeatletter
\newcases{mycases}{\quad}{%
\hfil$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$}{$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}
\makeatother



\begin{document}




\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize}]
%Five levels of a tree are drawn, depicting various subintervals of the closed interval [0,1].
%Here is the first level.
\coordinate (vertex_for_interval_between_0_and_1) at (0,0);
\node[anchor=north] (southern_edge_of_node_for_vertex_for_interval_between_0_and_1) at ($(vertex_for_interval_between_0_and_1) +(0,-0.1)$){$[0,1]$};
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate (tail_of_arrows_from_vertex_for_interval_between_0_and_1) at (southern_edge_of_node_for_vertex_for_interval_between_0_and_1);
%
%Here is the second level.
\draw[fill] (-0.75,-1.75) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (0.75,-1.75) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate (vertex_for_interval_between_0_and_1/2) at (-0.75,-1.75);
\node[anchor=north] at ($(vertex_for_interval_between_0_and_1/2) +(0,-0.1)$){$[0,$\raisebox{0.2em}{$\scriptstyle{1}$}\hspace{-0.2em}/\hspace{-0.2em}\raisebox{-0.2em}{$\scriptstyle{2}$}$]$};
\coordinate (vertex_for_interval_between_1/2_and_1) at (0.75,-1.75);
\node[anchor=north] at ($(vertex_for_interval_between_1/2_and_1) +(0,-0.1)$){$[$\raisebox{0.2em}{$\scriptstyle{1}$}\hspace{-0.2em}/\hspace{-0.2em}\raisebox{-0.2em}{$\scriptstyle{2}$}$,1]$};

%
%
%Arrows are drawn between the diagrams.
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten>=7.5pt, shorten<=7.5pt] (southern_edge_of_node_for_vertex_for_interval_between_0_and_1.south) to node[midway, anchor=south, yshift=0.25mm, sloped]
{$\raisebox{0.2em}{$\scriptstyle{1}$}\hspace{-0.2em}/\hspace{-0.2em}\raisebox{-0.2em}{$\scriptstyle{2}$}$} (vertex_for_interval_between_0_and_1/2.north);
%\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (southern_edge_of_node_for_vertex_for_interval_between_0_and_1.south) to node[midway, anchor=south, yshift=0.25mm, sloped]
%{\raisebox{0.2em}{$\scriptstyle{1}$}\hspace{-0.2em}/\hspace{-0.2em}\raisebox{-0.2em}{$\scriptstyle{2}$}} (vertex_for_interval_between_1/2_and_1.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}



\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no `shorten`, `shorten<` or `shorten>`, - *just like the error says* . You probably want to use `shorten <` and `shorten >` (notice the space)

Comment: @hpekristiansen Yes, an insertion of a space allowed the code to be compiled. What is the key to shorten both sides of the arrow by `7.5pt`?

Comment: @user143462 There is none. But you can define one yourself: `\tikzset{shorten/.style={shorten <={#1}, shorten >={#1}}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Where do I put that?

Comment: @user143462 Preferably somewhere in the preamble of your document after `\usepackage{tikz}`. That way, it is available everywhere in your document.